# Convert time in 24 hours to seconds

Tags: java

I have time in 24 hours using SimpleDateFormat using this code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat simpDate;

    simpDate = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(simpDate.format(date));

  }
}
```

I want to know how i would convert time in 24 hours to seconds. I want to be able to tell the next minute by just adding 60 seconds to the time stamp.

How can i convert the 24 hours time to seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.getTime()` will give you milliseconds.  You should be able to convert from there.

Comment: I dont want to get any date

Comment: This still has date in it `Date date = new Date();
      long diff = date.getTime();

      System.out.println(diff);`

Comment: Checked ur profile and am also doing a trading app ,it works anyways. Your solution will work.